# Retrieve the extension of the URL

Tags: php

I want to hit a URL - `http://www.blahblah.com/on/demand`

After each hit the aforementioned URL will generate an extension.

I.e. `http://www.blahblah.com/on/demand/C1212`

So, that I want to do is to take the generated extension (C1212)
I have no idea how can I do this? Does anyone know how can 
I do this with PHP?

Comment: How does it generate the extension? i.e. Where is it found?

Comment: cron ?? it is something which u can check

Comment: http://www.blahblah.com/on/demand redirects to http://www.blahblah.com/on/demand/C1212 ?

Comment: No, it doesn't redirect. You can see this only if you press INSPECT ELEMENT. And generally is using an IBM mechanism to make this generation

Comment: @NickRobertson Could you give an example for a site that does this so we could check whether you can read it in the headers of the site? (hence be able to use cURL to find out).

Comment: @NickRobertson — Is your question "How do I use PHP to get the URL from the href attribute of a link in an HTML document at a particular URL?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this answers you. Try this out.

```
<?php
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $extension = end(explode('/',$url));
    echo $extension;        
?>
```

Comment: Should i replace the REQUEST_URI with my URL?

Comment: Request_uri gives ur url. so u dont need to do anything